# ParseExact cannot parse a string in RFC 3339 Internet Date/Time format

Tags: c#, datetime, openapi, rfc3339

It seems that C# does not manage to parse a time in a valid RFC 3339 format:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2019-12-31T00:00:00.123456789+01:00", "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffffffzzz", null)
```

This line throws an exception, while this line works just fine:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2019-12-31T00:00:00.1234567+01:00", "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffffzzz", null)
```

So it seems there is a limit on milliseconds, but I cannot find out any documentation on that. Is this how it is supposed to be?

---

The reason want to parse this date is that I have have an input date field. We use OAS (Swagger) `date-time` format that quite clearly says that any date in RFC 3339 Internet Date/Time format should be valid. Now from the spec [here](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) section 5.6

```
time-secfrac    = "." 1*DIGIT
```

As far as I understand this means that up to 9 digits should be allowed and to be 100% compliant we have to allow these inputs, but it does not seem that C# even supports that.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: it's simple, .NET supports up to 7 digit of the miliseconds

Comment: IMHO, `1*DIGIT` means 1 or more digits.

Comment: That does not seem like a good spec with infinite amount of digits? But it's really hard to tell, I have not figured out exactly what does that mean

Comment: On my system, `DateTime.Parse("2019-12-31T00:00:00.123456789+01:00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` actually works and parses the value correctly (`DateTimeOffset` as well), using all the precision in the milliseconds it supports, even though there seems to be no way to specify an explicit format for it. So one possibility is a simple regex match to verify you've got this, and then parse it without `Exact`.

Comment: Then it's a bit of lying to say we accept this format to only drop some digits :)

Comment: Regardless of parsing, `DateTime` does not have sufficient precision to support all those digits -- ticks are accurate to 100 ns intervals only. This limit is carried over from Windows itself. If you need to preserve this exactly, you can't use `DateTime` to begin with.

Comment: BTW, RFC 3339 follows ISO8601 specification - which states that the number of digits for the decimal fraction is not limited by standard, but needs to be agreed to by the communicating parties.

Comment: So 1*DIGIT  means unlimited number of digits?

Comment: Yes.  1*DIGIT means at least 1 digit and up to an unlimited number of digits. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2234#section-3.6

Comment: @RobertMcKee: thanks for the link, I see now what it means, not that straightforward searching in these RFCs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netframework-4.8#fffffffSpecifier) specification, you can use only `fffffff`

> The `fffffff` custom format specifier represents the seven most
>   significant digits of the seconds fraction; that is, it represents the
>   ten millionths of a second in a date and time value.

In your first example

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2019-12-31T00:00:00.123456789+01:00", "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fffffffffzzz", null)
```

you are using `fffffffff` which is more precise for .NET custom date and time format strings

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, .NET supports seven most significant digits for milliseconds which is [The "fffffff" custom format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#fffffffSpecifier) are for.

> The "fffffff" custom format specifier represents the seven most
>   significant digits of the seconds fraction; that is, it represents the
>   ten millionths of a second in a date and time value.
>
> Although it's possible to display the ten millionths of a second
>   component of a time value, **that value may not be meaningful**. The
>   precision of date and time values depends on the resolution of the
>   system clock.

That means you are giving *not* meaningful data that are not supported for .NET Framework. I strongly suggest not doing that.

Comment: It's a bit disappointing that .Net does not support RFC 3339 fully, though it's quite meaningless to have that precision usually, it's still the spec...

Comment: It looks though I have misunderstood spec and it's actually unlimited digits

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the information in the other answers, if you cannot change your input and you still want to parse it, you may use one of the following solutions:

1. If your input will always be in the same format (i.e., has 9 seconds-fraction digits), you could just remove the two extra ones and proceed to parse it:

   ```
   string input = "2019-12-31T00:00:00.123456789+01:00";
   input = input.Remove(27, 2);
   // TODO: parse `input`.
   ```
2. If you don't know the number of the seconds-fraction digits beforehand, you may use something like this:

   ```
   string input = "2019-12-31T00:00:00.123456789+01:00";
   string format = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'FFFFFFFzzz";

   var regEx = new Regex(@"^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{1,7})\d*");
   input = regEx.Replace(input, "$1");
   DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(input, format, null);
   ```

Comment: There is no real reason to count and specify an exact number of `f`s. The `FFFFFFF` specifier will take care of a variable number of digits.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You're right. Thank you! Updated the answer.

Comment: Well, actually it seems I have misunderstood the spec, and infinite amount of digits is allowed for some reason, so I have just really limited the number to the maximum possible that is supported by .net, i.e. 7, so it is good enough :)